# if new news to make enabled, it is automatic removes enabled from the previous news

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

If new news to make enabled, it is automatic removes enabled from the previous news.

my callback:

post.rb

```
after_update :removes_enabled

def removes_enabled
  if enabled?
    self.enabled = false
  else
    self.enabled = true
  end
end
```

admin/post.rb

```
column :enabled do |status|
  status.enabled? ? action_label = "Disable" : action_label = "Enable"
  link_to(action_label, status_admin_news_path(status), method: :put )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable all previous posts, use the following code:

```
before_save :removes_enabled

def removes_enabled
  if enabled_changed? and enabled?
    Post.update_all( :enabled => false )
  end
end
```